# Difference between j = i + 1 and j = ++i;

Tags: java

I get different results, in the inner for loop for(j = i + 1...) and for(j = ++i...) in the code below. Please can anyone explain what happens in the for loop, during the initialization?

```
    public class DuplicateElementsInArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] names = {"Java", "Python", "C++", "JavaScript", "Java",  "Ruby", "C"};

            //This is a worst  Solution
            for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                //for(int j = i++; j < names.length; j++) {
                //for(int j = ++i; j < names.length; j++) {
                for(int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
                    //System.out.println("j: " + j);
                    if(names[i].equals(names[j]))
                        System.out.println("duplicate element: " + names[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between i++ vs i=i+1 in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281042/whats-the-difference-between-i-vs-i-i1-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: @GBlodgett no, it's not a duplicate of that. Note that the target of the assignment here is **`j`**, not **`i`** (i.e. a different variable on the left and right hand sides).

Answer (score 11):

`i + 1` leaves `i`'s current value unchanged.

`++i` increments `i`, i.e. `i`'s value is one greater after evaluating that expression.

Answer (score -1):

The first method is simply setting j to i+1.

The second method is an example of pre incrementing, which returns the exact same value in this case.

Read this for more specific info and usage on incrementing a variable [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

Comment: Please explain why I am getting total different wrong result when I am using j = ++i? When I am using j = i + 1 I am getting correct result.

Comment: ++i changes the value of i while j = i + 1 does not.  Thank you.

Comment: When you use j = ++i, the j value is set correctly however now you have also set i equal to itself + 1 which will skip every other iteration of the outer loop